# How can I omit the middle value number from the sequence?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, int

I'm trying to build a program that goes like this:
User enters 3 numbers.
System prints out ascending sequence of numbers from the lowest value number to highest value number input by the user.
Eg: if user inputs 1 then 4 then 8 it should print out 1,2,3,5,6,7,8 omitting 4 as it is the number with middle value.
How do I get the program to omit this number?

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int n3 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
int i = 0;
if ((n1 > n2) && (n2 > n3)) {
    for (i = n3; (i <= n1); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
else if ((n1 > n3) && (n3 > n2)) {
    for (i = n2; (i <= n1); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
else if ((n2 > n3) && (n3 > n1)) {
    for (i = n1; (i <= n2); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
else if ((n2 > n1) && (n1 > n3)) {
    for (i = n3; (i <= n2); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
else if ((n3 > n2) && (n2 > n1)) {
    for (i = n1; (i <= n3); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
else if ((n3 > n1) && (n1 > n2)) {
    for (i = n2; (i <= n3); i++) {
        String o = i + ",";
        System.out.print(o);
    }
}
System.out.println("\n" + "The sum of the sequence is " + i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over complicating things greatly.

Have the user enter 3 numbers and read them in three variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. Then just use a for-loop to iterate from `a` to `c`, and if the value is equal to `b` then don't print.

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int c = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

for(int i = a; i < c; i++)
{
   if(i != b)
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

Iteration makes your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find which numbers are highest middle and lowest. And then display the numbers as a list emmiting the middle number. You don't have nest the *for* statements inside the the *if* statements

This is because the for statement don't actually need to weather n1, n2 or only the highest and lowest and middle numbers. If you create intermediate variables to can assign to them before hand and not have nest for statement inside the ifs like you are doing.

Infact you can get rid of the if statments all together and use *Math.max(a,b)* (if your using java), and use intermediate variables before finding what are highest, middle and lowest numbers.

you might want to try some thing like this:

```
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n3 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int higher1 = Math.max(n1, n2);
        int lower1 =  Math.min(n1, n2);

        int lowest = Math.min(lower1, n3);
        int highest = Math.max(higher1, n3);

        int middle;
        if (n3 < lower1 ) {
            middle = lower1;
        } else if (n3 > higher1) {
            middle = higher1;
        } else {
            middle = n3;
        }

        System.out.println("The highest is: " + highest);
        System.out.println("The middle is: " + middle);
        System.out.println("The lowest is: " + lowest);


        for ( int count = lowest; count <= highest; count++){
            if (count != middle) {
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
```